# Magento2 - Set up different currency for different website for same product

Tags: magento2, currency, multi-website, conversion

My requirement is : I want to setup different Currencies for different website on my `Magento2.3` store.

eg: For `Website A,` default `Currency is  A`.

For `Website B`, default `Currency is B`.

Now what I will do is, I will setup price for a product in default website. I want the price to be calculated automatically for `Website A` in `Currency A` and for `Website B in Currency B`.

Is there any extension/ Module free or paid , which helps me in achieving this functionality.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To display different currency price in different website for same product . You can follow these steps.

```
Step 1: Login to your Magento Admin account;

Step 2: Navigate to Stores → Configuration;

Step 3: Under the General tab, find the Currency Setup settings;
Step 4: Choose your preferred Base Currency, Default Display Currency, and 
Allowed Currencies;

Step 5: Refresh your cache if you have previously set your cache settings to 
enabled.
```

To display different price for different website.

```
Step 1: Login to your Magento Admin account;

Step 2: Navigate to Stores → Configuration;

Step 3: Click the Catalog tab and choose the Catalog section;

Step 4: Under the Catalog Price Scope, choose the Website option in order to 
display different product prices on different websites.

Step 5: To display the same product in different currency units on different websites, you’ll need to go to Catalog → Products, click the names of the products you want to get listed on those sites, scroll down to the section called Product in Websites and leave a checkmark in front of the Names of the Websites you want those products to appear.
```

Let me know if it is helpful to you.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, i will try this. But does not the last step seems to be very tedious. Step 5: To display the same product in different currency units on different websites, you’ll need to go to Catalog → Products, click the names of the products you want to get listed on those sites, scroll down to the section called Product in Websites and leave a checkmark in front of the Names of the Websites you want those products to appear. Can this be done at the time of creating a product? I mean if by default i want all my products to be displayed on all my websites ?

Comment: yes, you can do it by grammatically or also at time of product import , you can pass this attribute true value

Comment: Did not get you. Which attribute u are talking about? in my csv  i dont want to declare different prices for different website. I will set one price for default website ,and for rest  the price should be calculated automatically

Comment: product_websites attribute in csv file to add websites for product in which you want to show your products.

Comment: What about this question "n my csv i dont want to declare different prices for different website. I will set one price for default website ,and for rest the price should be calculated automatically "

Comment: for that you need to setup different currency exchange rate as given below steps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104080/discussion-between-nafisa-and-manish-chaubey).

Comment: This does not help.